# About Yaajooj and Maajooj ( Arabic: يَأْجُوج وَمَأْجُوج‎ )

Tags: yajooj-and-majooj

I want to know that it's said that [Yaajooj and Maajooj](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gog_and_Magog) live behind a really tall and strong wall (made by hazrat [zulqurnain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhul-Qarnayn)). but if it's so then it means that they are cut off from rest of the world and can't be contacted. So no one is able to tell them about hidayat and Islam.. and they won't be able to accept Islam. Still it's their mistake?
 
They don't know anything about Islam.. or is there any way for Allah to preach hidayat.
 Please clear my mind.

Comment: Could you please translate the Arabic words in this question into English?

Comment: Please follow English orthography rules.

Comment: @Daniel, the Arabic word used here "hidayat" or "hidayah" can roughly be translated as "guidance." (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidayah)

Answer (score 2):

Yajuj and Majuj are the Arabic words for the Hebrew Gog and Magog which is the Hebrew version of the Assyrian words Gugu and Matgugu. These names refer to a people whom the Greeks knew as Amazons and Scythians and the Persians knew as Alan or the grass nomads of Central Asia. A genetic link has been established between the Mongols and the [ancient Scythians](http://www.redicecreations.com/article.php?id=22764). So, the Mongol invasions (1206-1324) may be the fulfillment of the prophecy of 18:99.  According to Wiki:

> The Scythians (/ˈsɪθi.ən/ or /ˈsɪði.ən/; from Greek Σκύθης, Σκύθοι) were Iranian-speaking equestrian tribes who inhabited large areas in the central Eurasian steppes between the 7th century BC and 4th century AD. Their territories during the Iron Age were known to classical Greek sources as "Scythia". Their historical appearance coincided with the rise of equestrian semi-nomadism from the Carpathian Mountains of Europe to Mongolia in the Far East during the 1st millennium BC. The "classical Scythians" known to ancient Greek historians were located in the northern Black Sea and fore-Caucasus region. However, other Scythian groups encountered in Near Eastern and Achaemenid sources existed in Central Asia.

The Achaemenid sources are a reference to the Achaemenid Empire which was founded by Cyrus the Great, who is referred to as Al Dhul Qarnain in the Quran. A bas relief of Cyrus the Great wearing his two horned crown can be seen at Pasargade in Iran:
http://www.oznet.net/cyrus/original.htm

The wall referred to in the Surah 18:93-98 refers to the Daryal Passes in N Georgia, in the central Greater Caucasus Mountains. Daryal is from the Persian words Dar el Alan which means the gates of the Alan. The Alan were a Sarmatian/Scythian tribe of grass nomads who were also known as Gugu/Matgugu to the Assyrians, Gog and Magog to the Hebrews and Yjuj and Majuj to the Arabs.

The Hebrew historian Titus Flavius Josephus (37-100 CE), who was a Zealot turned loyal Roman citizen (Zealots were anti Roman occupation Hebrew insurgents) wrote that Alexander the Great built iron gates in some unspecified area. Thus, the name Alexander was associated with the later Persian fortifications at Daryal and Derbend in Georgia. There is absolutely no evidence that Alexander the Great built any fortifications in this area. However, the later Persian fortifications in Daryal and Derbend lend credence to Cyrus the Great, the founder of the Achaeminid Empire, building the original gates, which were later rebuilt by the Persian Sassanid and Parthian Dynasties. Cyrus was later killed in December of 530 BCE of by a grass nomad tribe known as the Massagetae who were related to the Scythians in their dress and mode of living; they fought on horseback and on foot.
Cyrus was considered to be a messiah (Isaiah 45:1) or an anointed one by the Hebrews. He is extensively mentioned in the Biblical books of 2 Chronicles, Ezra, Isaiah and Daniel. The Hebrew tribes in Arabia knew about Cyrus and asked the Prophet (pbuh) about him under his cryptic title, 'the two horned one', which brought about the revelation in Surah Al Kahf.

And Allah (swt) knows best!

Answer (score 0):

Brother Salam,
I will be happy to answer your question since your mind is occupied by the very idea of aloofness of Yajooj and Majooj.
Your is bothered by these question that why they were not granted guidance. Did any messenger were send towards them?
Before proceeding I would like to briefly explain a few things so you will be able to understand the whole idea.
First of all the Holy Quraan is the source of all knowledge. Secondly the hadith are consulted for deeper insight.  Knowledge of Hadith is most authentic for the understanding of typical religious matters.
No scholar can fabricate anything in Deen from himself.  That is call innovation rather conspiracy.
;   Yajooj and Majooj are the descents of Yafith As. Who was one of the three sons of hazrat Noah AS. So one thing is they are human.
It's also proven by some hadiths.
They were not cut off from the world in beginning like all the ancient nations of world. They were ambitious people.
According to Hadith they were agriculturist by profession According to one of the hadith. Holy Quraa: n says that they were and corrupt by nature who used to oppress weak people and claimed themselves to be most powerful on earth.
When Dhulqar nayan reached the village of people who were oppressed by the cruelties of yajooj and Majooj. He asked them about their sadness. They told him yajooj majooj invasion from a passage between two mountains.  They also asked for his help in exchange of money. But Dhulqar Nain declined their offer by saying that he had everything by the grace of Allah. But agreed to help them.
At that point of time they were cut off from the world when Dhulqar naon imprisoned them behind the wall.
But according to hadith messengers were sent towards them before that but they would kill them. They chose their own way of living and disobeyed Allah's command.
Hadith is so that they dig the wall everyday break Into it but by the end of day when it's close to break open one of them say that let's go back we will dig it tomorrow.  When they come next day the wall regains it's original thickness again by the grace of Allah. One day will come when one of the command among will say let's go back we will dig ift tomorrow Inshallah. When they will come next day they will find it in same shape as they left it and they will break open. That is one of the signs of Qayamah.
The use word Inshallah by one of them clearly testify that Allah send messenger for their Guidance.  They refuse obey Allah's command.
Thanks. They are,still imprisoned behind wall.  That's why you can't see them anywhere.
Allah say in sura Anmbya in para 16 that we will set them free before judgment day and you will see them sliding down every high place
So thanks brother. I hope this article remove confusion from your mind .
Thanks